# Angular2 pass Child Component form values as Observable to parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to pass the child component form values to parent component as an Observable. When the form is submitted, the child components form values are not accessible until an event like selecting something from one of the drop downs is triggered. Any ideas on how to access the default values along with the existing valueChanges event?

```
//Child Component
import {Component, Output} from '@angular/core'
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup} from '@angular/common'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'state',
  providers: [FormBuilder],
  templateUrl: 'app/state.html',
  directives: []
})

export class State {

  statesDropDownValues = ['NJ', 'NY', 'PA', 'CA'];
  countriesDropDownValues = ['USA', 'CANADA', 'MEXICO', 'INDIA'];

  stateForm: ControlGroup

  @Output()
  stateFormChanges: Observable<any>;  

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.stateForm = fb.group({
      'state': 'NY',
      'country': 'USA',
      'zip': '10017'
    });

    this.stateFormChanges = this.stateForm.valueChanges;
  }

}

// Parent Component
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from '@angular/common'
import {State} from './state'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [FormBuilder],
  templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
  directives: [State]
})

export class App {
  registrationForm: ControlGroup;

  state: string;
  country: string;
  zip: string;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.registrationForm = fb.group({
      'name': 'Test Name',
      'email': 'abc@xyz.com'
    });
  }

  handleStateFormChanges(formValues) {
    this.state = formValues.state;
    this.country = formValues.country;
    this.zip = formValues.zip;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    alert('Entered Name: ' + this.registrationForm.value.name);
    alert('State Selected: ' + this.state);
    alert('Country Selected: ' + this.country);
    alert('Zip Entered: ' + this.zip);
  }
}
```

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8tsm9sYeH8d8ulfqQKxY?p=info) for my code.